# Overlay divs without leaving the parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make two divs function normally on top of each other without using absolute positioning? I need it to **stay within the parent so when the parent moves or resizes it does the same**

Code: (Using Bootstrap 4)

```
<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I'm trying to make to the button group(`.col-btns`) overlay his sibling `.col-content`, is that possible while maintaining his reference to the parent container?

I know I could use a negative top margin, but the value of the margin has to be equal its current height since it will vary, and its height has to be equal its parent height which also varies, is that possible?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8as9dmf2/

Here's an example of why I need it to keep its parent's reference (my actual context): http://jsfiddle.net/n0m4cu5s/15/

Maybe it can only be done with Javascript?

Comment: May I ask why you do not want to use absolute positioning? it would be really easy to achieve the result by doing though.

Comment: @caiovisk because it wouldn't move and resize with the parent? Or maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the container `.outer-col` a grid container.

Then you can assign both the content and buttons to the same `grid-row` and `grid-column`.

**Example**:

```css
.outer-col {
  display: grid;
}

.col-content,
.col-btns {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.col-btns {
  opacity: 0;
}

.outer-col:hover .col-btns {
  opacity: .75;
}

.outer-col:hover .col-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `position: absolute;` will do the job here.

Code below will position your `.col-btns` on the centre of its parent.

```
.content-group .col-btns {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

So you can position your buttons wherever you want to by changing the `top` and/or `tranform` values.

```css
.col-btns{
  opacity : 0;
}
.outer-col:hover .col-btns{
  opacity : .75;
  transition : opacity .5s ease;
}
.content-group .col-btns {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Just to show an example */
.content-group.small {
  height: 100px;
}
.content-group.med {
  height: 200px;
}
.content-group.big {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0 content-group">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button> 
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0 content-group small">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here small
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button> 
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0 content-group med">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here medium
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button> 
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col outer-col border m-3 p-0 content-group big">
  <div class="col-content w-100 text-center">
    Text or Image here large
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group w-100 col-btns">
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary rmv-col">
      Remove
    </button>
    <button class="btn w-50 btn-outline-secondary edit-col">
      Edit
    </button> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The op clearly said `How can I make two divs function normally on top of each other without using absolute positioning? `

Comment: Have you ready the question I asked him?? He is not sure if absolute positioning would fit on it... you clearly missed `because it wouldn't move and resize with the parent? Or maybe I'm wrong`